# Generating statistical reports

Tags: php, laravel

I want to generate statistical reports and I have many different `where` clauses so the function became long. I did much refactoring, but it is not enough. Can someone help me with some techniques that these techniques make the function short and easily readable?

```
public static function allRejUserByProv($prov = '', $gender = '', $dist = '', $ttc = '')
    {
        if (!empty($gender) && !empty($prov) && !empty($dist))
        {
            return self::where('decision', '3')->where('gender', $gender)->where('p_province', $prov)->where('p_district', $dist)->count();
        }
        if (!empty($prov) && !empty($dist))
        {
            return self::where('decision', '3')->where('p_province', $prov)->where('p_district', $dist)->count();
        }
        if (!empty($prov) && !empty($gender))
        {
            return self::where('decision', '3')->where('p_province', $prov)->where('gender', $gender)->count();
        }
        if(!empty($gender) && !empty($ttc))
        {
            return self::where('decision', '3')->where('ttc_name', $ttc)->where('gender', $gender)->count();
        }
        if(!empty($ttc))
        {
            return self::where('decision', '3')->where('ttc_name', $ttc)->count();
        }
        if (!empty($gender))
        {
            return self::where('decision', '3')->where('gender', $gender)->count();
        }
        if (!empty($prov))
        {
            return self::where('decision', '3')->where('p_province', $prov)->count();
        }

        return self::where('decision', '3')->count();
    }
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
public function resultTTC($prov, $dist, $ttc)
{
return [
  'rejected'             => number_format(self::allRejUserByProv($prov, '', $dist, $ttc)),
        'rejected_male'        => number_format(self::allRejUserByProv($prov, '1', $dist, $ttc)),
        'rejected_female'      => number_format(self::allRejUserByProv($prov, '2', $dist, $ttc)),

]
```

Comment: is it correct to assume that you want to add a `where` clause for each argument that is not empty? Or there is a cascade/priority in place? For example when `prov`, `dist` and `gender` are all not empty the second `if` clause will always get matched and return.

Comment: I assume PHP has no list comprehensions? (I don't know much PHP at all)

Comment: one of the if clauses will execute base on condition @Alex Andrei and yeah add where clauses base on !empty

Comment: Please [edit] your title to tell us a bit about *what your code does*. Making your title *distinctive* implies using a title that *not every single other on-topic question on this site* could use...

Comment: Let me ask differently, do you want a where clause for **each** argument that is not empty?

Comment: @AlexAndrei Yeah exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to do the `where` for every non-empty value. You can do the following:

```
public static function allRejUserByProv($prov = '', $gender = '', $dist = '', $ttc = '')
{
    $fields = [
        'gender' => $gender,
        'p_district' => $dist,
        'p_province' => $prov,
        'ttc_name' => $ttc
    ];

    $result = self::where('decision', '3');

    foreach ($fields as $attr => $value) {
        if(! empty($value)) {
            $result = $result->where($attr, $value);
        }
    }

    return $result->count();
}
```

This way you will remove the multiple `if`s.

If you will **always** use `number_format` to format the return value why not just adding it to the function:

```
return number_format($result->count());
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks man should I pass the decision also as argument cause I have many of this method in my Model so in every function the (gender, p_district, p_province, ttc_name ) is the same but one where clause is deferent in every function so this technique will make my code more dynamic and readable ??

Comment: Sure, always pass arguments instead of hard coding values. I would also suggest to rename variables and the function with meaningful names ( `$province` instead of `$prov` for example)

Comment: I am editing the code please look at once how I am calling this method

Comment: Thanks Again @webNeat you did the best it worked perfectly